# ¿Como crear un DataFrame desde un array de listados?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Como crear un DataFrame desde un array de listados non indexados indexandole sobre los arrays ?

Por ejemplo

```
[[{'count': 6L, 'item_id': 11313}, {'count': 6L, 'item_id': 11348},
{'count': 1L, 'item_id': 11338}, ],[{'count': 4L, 'item_id': 11311},
{'count': 3L, 'item_id': 11281}]]
```

Debe dar un dataframe como el siguiente :

```
+---------+-------+---------+
| user_id | count | item_id |
+---------+-------+---------+
|    0    |    6  |  11313  |
|    0    |    6  |  11348  |
|    0    |    1  |  11338  |
|    1    |   4   |  11311  |
|    1    |   3   |  11281  |
```

Comment: Marine te he respondido pensando que el dataframe lo quieres en Pandas, pero me he dado cuenta que no lo haces explícito. Si no es así y lo que quieres es un SFrame especificalo, por favor. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un DataFrame por cada sublista y usar `pandas.concat` para concatenarlos. Para crear la columna `users_id` te vales del argumento `keys`. Dado que `keys` nos crea un multiindex usamos `rest_index` para pasar `user_id` a una columna y reiniciar el índice de nuestro dataframe final:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = [[{'count': 6L, 'item_id': 11313}, {'count': 6L, 'item_id': 11348},
          {'count': 1L, 'item_id': 11338}, ],[{'count': 4L, 'item_id': 11311},
          {'count': 3L, 'item_id': 11281}]]


res = pd.concat(objs = (pd.DataFrame(f) for f in datos),
                keys = (n for n in range(len(datos))),
                names = ['user_id'])

res.reset_index(level = 0, inplace = True)
res.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> >>> res
>
>    user_id  count  item_id
> 0        0      6    11313
> 1        0      6    11348
> 2        0      1    11338
> 3        1      4    11311
> 4        1      3    11281
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción a lo que plantea [@FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla) sería crear primero algo que entienda [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas).

En mi caso primero creo un diccionario que puede entender [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) y luego creo el dataframe a partir del diccionario.

```
import pandas as pd

kk = [[{'count': 6, 'item_id': 11313},
       {'count': 6, 'item_id': 11348},
       {'count': 1, 'item_id': 11338}],
      [{'count': 4, 'item_id': 11311}, 
       {'count': 3, 'item_id': 11281}]]

resultado = {'user_id': [], 'count': [], 'item_id': []}
for i, lista in enumerate(kk):
    for d in lista:
        resultado['user_id'].append(i)
        resultado['count'].append(d['count'])
        resultado['item_id'].append(d['item_id'])

df = pd.DataFrame(resultado)
```